# Ubuntu not booting up

Tags: installation, boot, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop which was running Windows XP. This is what I did:

- Downloaded Ubuntu 13.10
- Launched it in .exe (*?*)
- My PC rebooted.

There is no display any more, and no BIOS any more. What should I do?

Original post in French: https://askubuntu.com/revisions/363052/1

Comment: This is an English-only site. Please keep your posts in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write the iso file to a bootable USB (Creez a USB boot). Then do it with the USB boot.

<sub>Original post in French: https://askubuntu.com/revisions/363054/1</sub>

Answer (score 0):

*Version en français ci-dessous.*

Welcome on Ask Ubuntu and on Ubuntu!

Normally you should have dowloaded an ISO file instead of an EXE one. Try doing it again by following the instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

---

Bienvenue sur Ask Ubuntu et sur Ubuntu en général !

Normalement, ce que tu as téléchargé devrait être un .iso et non pas un .exe. C'est-à-dire qu'il faut « graver » une clé USB avec ce fichier, puis démarrer le PC depuis la clé, pour ensuite suivre les instructions. C'est très bien expliqué là : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/

Bonne chance !